# Как создать процедуру в mysql

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

Первый раз пишу процедуру. У меня есть таблица бронирований, которая создается так:

```
CREATE TABLE bookings
(
    id          INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    room_id     INT  NOT NULL,
    user_id     INT  NOT NULL,
    start_date  DATE NOT NULL,
    end_date    DATE NOT NULL,
    delete_time DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (room_id) REFERENCES rooms (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

Мне необходимо написать процедуру, в которую будет передано 3 значения: дата заезда, дата отъезда и номер комнаты.
В самой процедуре мне надо получить все бронирования на данный номер если они есть и проверить, не пересекаются ли даты переданные в процедуру с датами уже существующих бронирований. Если такое не происходит мне надо вернуть false, Если пересечение есть, то вернуть true.
Учитывая что это мой первый опыт, я даже не знаю с чего начать. Читал про процедуры, и насколько понимаю мне нужен курсор? Пытался сделать так:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `validate_booking_date`(IN room_id INT, IN start_booking_date DATE, IN end_booking_date DATE)
BEGIN
    declare validate TINYINT;
    with b as (
        select * from bookings bok where bok.room_id = room_id
    );
    if start_booking_date > b.start_date then 
        SET validate = 1;        
        select validate;

    else 
        set validate = 0;        
        select validate;
    end if;
END
```

Но ничего не выходит.
У меня есть данная проверка в коде, и вот как она выглядит на java:

```
booking.getStartDate().after(b.getStartDate()) && booking.getStartDate().before(b.getEndDate())
                    || (booking.getEndDate().after(b.getStartDate()) && booking.getEndDate().before(b.getEndDate()))
                    || (b.getStartDate().after(booking.getStartDate()) && b.getStartDate().before(booking.getEndDate())))
                    || (b.getEndDate().after(booking.getStartDate()) && b.getEndDate().before(booking.getEndDate()))
                    || (b.getStartDate().getTime() == booking.getStartDate().getTime() || b.getStartDate().getTime() == booking.getEndDate().getTime())
                    || (b.getEndDate().getTime() == booking.getStartDate().getTime() || b.getEndDate().getTime() == booking.getEndDate().getTime())
```

в данном коде b - уже существующее бронирование а booking - новое, которое и надо проверить.

Comment: Что именно не происодит, не создает или не правильно работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не получается создать

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3`

то дело в `WITH`

```
with b as (
        select * from bookings bok where bok.room_id = room_id
    );
```

вместо него можно использовать `SET`

```
SET @b = (select start_date from (select * from bookings bok where bok.room_id = room_id) as t);
```

**Вариант 1:**

Для переменной нужно использовать `@` и весь запрос должен быть в скобках, а внутренний иметь алиас (тут не важно какой например: t).

В итоге должно быть так:

```
DELIMITER // 
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `validate_booking_date`(IN room_id INT, IN start_booking_date DATE, IN end_booking_date DATE)
BEGIN
    declare validate TINYINT; 
    SET @b = (select start_date from (select * from bookings bok where bok.room_id = room_id) as t);
    if start_booking_date > @b then
        SET validate = 1;
        select validate; 
    else 
        set validate = 0;
        select validate; end if;
END //
```

если `start_booking_date > start_date` для комнаты вернет `0`
если нет вернет `1`

**Вариант 2**

Можно использовать конструкцию `SELECT INTO`

```
DELIMITER // 
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `validate_booking_date`(IN room_id INT, IN start_booking_date DATE, IN end_booking_date DATE)
BEGIN
    declare validate TINYINT; 
    DECLARE b DATE;
    SELECT start_date INTO b from bookings bok where bok.room_id = room_id;    
    if start_booking_date > b then
        SET validate = 1;
        select validate; 
    else 
        set validate = 0;
        select validate; end if;
END //
```

**Важно**: запрос для `b` должен возвращать не более одного значения, в случае если там будет список произойдет ошибка.

`#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row`

Думаю там должно быть что-то типа:

```
SELECT
    start_date 
From
    bookings bok 
WHERE 
    bok.room_id=room_id 
    AND (
        (start_booking_date BETWEEN bok.start_date AND bok.end_date) 
        OR 
        (end_booking_date BETWEEN bok.start_date AND bok.end_date)
    )
```